Boost program_options: Mixing positional arguments and named arguments
I am using boost::program_options to make a simple executable with the following general syntax:
program --command <cmd> [args]

For example:
program --command run --listen locahost --port 8080 

I would like to make the command part a positional argument, so that the user is not forced to type it everytime. Therefore it should also work like this:
program run --listen locahost --port 8080

Each command has its own set of arguments, and all are optional.
The following code does function properly only when the positional arguments are not used. This looks fine according to the boost docs (unless I am missing a point). When adding positional argument, I get an exception on parsing that says too many positional options have been specified on the command line
// Define the options
po::options_description args("Generic options");
args.add_options()
    ("command", po::value<std::string>(), "command to execute");
    ("arg1", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 1")
    ("arg2", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 2")
    ("arg3", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 3")
    ("arg4", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 4");

po::positional_options_description positional;
positional.add("command", 1);

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(args)
    .positional(positional) // Problem here
    .allow_unregistered()
    .run(), vm);

// Check if positional command is present
if (vm.count("command")) {
    std::string command = vm["command"].as<std::string>();
    std::cout << "Command: " << command << "\n";
}

po::notify(vm);

std::cout << "arg1: " << vm["arg1"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
std::cout << "arg2: " << vm["arg2"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
std::cout << "arg3: " << vm["arg3"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
std::cout << "arg4: " << vm["arg4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";


I believe the basic issue is that it doesn’t know that your subcommand options take arguments, so it tries to include those as positional arguments.  allow_unregistered is worthless that way.

Like the commenter probably intended, the unknown options --listen, locahost, --port and 8080 are taken as verbatim positional arguments. There's only one defined.
However, your question text and code are contradicting each-other
Question Text
Your text description suggests you wanted things to work without unregistered options:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Define the options
    po::options_description args("Generic options");
    args.add_options()                                              //
        ("command", po::value<std::string>(), "command to execute") //
        ("listen", po::value<std::string>(), "bind address")        //
        ("port", po::value<std::string>(), "TCP port")              //
        ;

    po::positional_options_description positional;
    positional.add("command", 1);

    po::variables_map vm;
    store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(args)
            .positional(positional) 
             //.allow_unregistered()
            .run(),
            vm);

    notify(vm);

    // Check if positional command is present
    if (vm.contains("command")) {
        std::string command = vm["command"].as<std::string>();
        std::cout << "Command: " << command << "\n";
    }

    if (vm.contains("listen"))
        std::cout << "listen: " << vm["listen"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
    if (vm.contains("port"))
        std::cout << "port: " << vm["port"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
}

Printing
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_program_options && ./a.out run --listen locahost --port 8080

Command: run
listen: locahost
port: 8080

Question Code
On the other hand, your code suggests that you wanted to go the other way: all in on position arguments. This could work if you don't plan on using any long --options yourself:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Define the options
    po::options_description args("Generic options");
    args.add_options()                                              //
        ("command", po::value<std::string>(), "command to execute") //
        ("arg1", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 1")            //
        ("arg2", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 2")            //
        ("arg3", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 3")            //
        ("arg4", po::value<std::string>(), "argument 4")            //
        ;

    po::positional_options_description positional;
    positional.add("command", 1);
    positional.add("arg1", 1);
    positional.add("arg2", 1);
    positional.add("arg3", 1);
    positional.add("arg4", 1);

    po::variables_map vm;

    auto style = po::command_line_style::default_style & ~po::command_line_style::allow_long;

    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
                  .options(args)
                  .style(style)
                  .positional(positional)
                  .run(),
              vm);

    po::notify(vm);
    // Check if positional command is present
    if (vm.count("command"))
        std::cout << "Command: " << vm["command"].as<std::string>() << "\n";

    if (vm.contains("arg1"))
        std::cout << "arg1: " << vm["arg1"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
    if (vm.contains("arg2"))
        std::cout << "arg2: " << vm["arg2"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
    if (vm.contains("arg3"))
        std::cout << "arg3: " << vm["arg3"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
    if (vm.contains("arg4"))
        std::cout << "arg4: " << vm["arg4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
}

Which prints:
Command: run
arg1: --listen
arg2: locahost
arg3: --port
arg4: 8080

Summary, Hints
At this rate, I'd simplify without Program-Options:
Live
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string_view> vm(argv+1, argv+argc);

    enum { command, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 };

    std::cout << "Command: " << quoted(vm.at(command)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Arg1: " << quoted(vm.at(arg1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Arg2: " << quoted(vm.at(arg2)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Arg3: " << quoted(vm.at(arg3)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Arg4: " << quoted(vm.at(arg4)) << "\n";
}

Printing
Command: "run"
Arg1: "--listen"
Arg2: "locahost"
Arg3: "--port"
Arg4: "8080"

Alternatively, consider parsing commands from the original token stream using a parser framework like e.g. Boost Spirit

for example Boost::Spirit struggle with parsing a String
or even in hybrid: boost program_options values with different types

